# Issue while loop , TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Issues in while loop instead of checking if typeof is different of undefined .

Here my code to purge data of duplicate values.

```
    function purge() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp
    .openByUrl(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getUrl())
    .getSheetByName("Feuille 1");

  var ssdata = ss.getDataRange().getValues();

  var m = 1;
  while (typeof ssdata[m][0] != undefined) { 

    var j = 1; 

    while (typeof ssdata[m + j][0] != undefined) {

    while (ssdata[m + j][0] === ssdata[m][0]) {

      if (ssdata[m + j][0] == ssdata[m][0]) {

        SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getUrl()).getSheetByName("Feuille 1").getRange(m + j + 1, 1, 1, 15).clearContent();

      }
      j++;
    }
    m++;
  }
  }

}
```

How to solve it ???

Comment: undefined is actually "undefined"

Comment: Did you want to delete only contiguous duplicates or any duplicate in the data range?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 while (typeof ssdata[m][0] != undefined) {
```

by

```
  while (m < ssdata.length) {
```

or by

```
  while (ssdata[m]) {
```

Comment: Ok thanks 
It's works with while (m < ssdata.length)